# Does Cygwin support multithreading when starting multiple backgrounded commands?

Tags: cygwin, multi-core, multiple-instances

Let's say I have a bash script like the following:

```
prog list1.txt &
prog list2.txt &
prog list3.txt &
wait
```

will the "prog" instances be launched in a multithreaded environment (like, 1 process per core), or will all of them be launched in the same core?

Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the operating system to schedule processes. Cygwin doesn't do anything special.

Assuming your OS isn't horribly broken, it will schedule the processes to cores in whatever way it thinks is best. That should be pretty close to whatever actually is best since OSes worth using are designed by people who know what they're doing.

Comment: I see... thanks for the concise explanation. I don't have much choice regarding the OS, though... :-)